Create a Dataframe from a series, and specifically how to re-name a column in it (example: with NAs / NaNs)
New to Python.  I come from a SQL world where I'm used to running queries and applying them.  It's handy to take a list of things, get their count and then use a subset of that count (like the top 5) and apply it to other data.  With Python/Pandas, I still have not quite grokked the process.  By way of example:
A simple dataset:
`import pandas as pd

dataset = (
    [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    [1,None,3,4,5,6],
    [1,None,3,4,5,6],
    [1,2,None,4,5,6],
    [1,None,3,None,5,6],
    [1,2,None,4,5,6],
    [1,None,3,None,5,6],
    [1,2,3,4,5,None],
    [1,2,3,4,5,None]
)    
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F'])`

Then make a dataframe to find the NaNs:
    nan_df = df.isna()
Then count the instances of each row:
    grouped_nan = nan_df.groupby(['A','B', 'C', 'D','E', 'F'], sort=True).value_counts()
The original set I was working was had ~200 rows.  This simplified example yields this:
A      B      C      D      E      F    
False  False  False  False  False  False    1
                                   True     2
              True   False  False  False    2
       True   False  False  False  False    2
                     True   False  False    2
Name: count, dtype: int64

This is where I run into trouble.  The things I want to do are best done in a Dataframe (the above is a Series).  The following makes it a DataFrame:
    grouped_nan_df = grouped_nan.to_frame()
But it doesn't bring along the last column (the count) in a way I can manage.  I can see it, but I can't do anything with it.
If I try to reference the column with the counts, it does not recognize it.
If I try to rename that last column it doesn't work:
`grouped_nan_df.rename(columns={grouped_nan_df.columns[5]:"new_count"}, inplace=True)`

gives the error "index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1".
What I want at the end is a DataFrame that includes the counts. Is there a way to get there?
Any help appreciated!
Andy

Just reset_index() after value_counts.

@mozway Thank you!  For some reason, when I do that and later try to call the column, although it type() as a dataframe I get an error that says 'DataFrame' object is not callable'  The answer below is along the same lines as what you suggested but uses size which I can then call.  I don't know what the difference is other than that.

you most likely don't need groupby. I believe your error is due to something incorrect you did in the code that is not shown here. This shouldn't happen. Try to start a fresh shell/notebook with your minimal example. See my answer below. NB. value_counts should be preferred over groupby.size as it's more efficient.

IIUC, you can just use groupby with as_index=False and then take the group size:
out = nan_df.groupby(['A','B', 'C', 'D','E', 'F'], as_index=False).size()

Output:
       A      B      C      D      E      F  size
0  False  False  False  False  False  False     1
1  False  False  False  False  False   True     2
2  False  False   True  False  False  False     2
3  False   True  False  False  False  False     2
4  False   True  False   True  False  False     2


Thank you!  I don't know exactly why that becomes as dataframe rather than a series as before, but it works and returns as a dataframe.  I tried to upvote the answer but it wouldn't let me (I don't have enough reputation) - sorry about that.

@AndyB the as_index=False brings the groupby columns into the result, hence you get a dataframe, not a series indexed by those columns.

Just adding reset_index should be enough:
Also, since you're using all columns, you don't need groupby:
import pandas as pd

dataset = (
    [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    [1,None,3,4,5,6],
    [1,None,3,4,5,6],
    [1,2,None,4,5,6],
    [1,None,3,None,5,6],
    [1,2,None,4,5,6],
    [1,None,3,None,5,6],
    [1,2,3,4,5,None],
    [1,2,3,4,5,None]
)    
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F'])

nan_df = df.isna()

grouped_nan = (nan_df[['A','B', 'C', 'D','E', 'F']]
               .value_counts()
               .reset_index()
               )

print(grouped_nan)

Or, simply:
nan_df = df.isna()

grouped_nan = nan_df.value_counts().reset_index()

print(grouped_nan)

       A      B      C      D      E      F  count
0  False  False  False  False  False  False      1
1  False  False  False  False  False   True      2
2  False  False   True  False  False  False      2
3  False   True  False  False  False  False      2
4  False   True  False   True  False  False      2


I ran timeit on the two solutions and the timing is essentially the same on my machine.

@Nick interesting, I'm pretty sure value_counts used to be faster. I've just checked the source and it looks like value_counts uses a groupby.size internally. I don't know if my memory's failing of if the code was improved ;)

One thing is sure, groupby+value_counts is not needed!

Interesting. So they basically run the same code, hence the same timing. As you say though, the groupby is completely redundant in that case.

@Nick Series.value_counts is faster that groupby.size (it uses a different algorithm), this is indeed not the case for DataFrames.

Interesting again. So now the question is why dataframes don't use the faster algorithm...

Thank you both.  Learned something here!  I think the SQL made me think the groupby was needed.
